# Size of the set of all $k$-size subsets with conditionally intersection

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set of all $k$-size subsets, say $\mathcal{A}$ of $\left\{1,2,...,n \right\}$ with the property that the size of the intersection of any two subsets of that is less than $t$. Prove that:

$$
\left|\mathcal{A}\right|\leq\frac{\Big(\begin{array}{cc}n\\t\end{array}\Big)}{\Big(\begin{array}{cc}k\\t\end{array}\Big)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subset of size $k$ has exactly $\binom{k}{t}$ subsets of size $t$. Since all of these are distinct ( no two subsets of size $k$ can share the same subset of size $t$) and there are exactly $\binom{n}{t}$ possibilities for the subsets of size $t$ we conclude there can be no more than $\binom{n}{t}/\binom{k}{t}$ subsets of size $k$.